# Converting SQL system datetime to non-standard format

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, datepart

All,

I've been wracking my brains trying to figure this one out. I need to convert SQL timestamp to a non-standard format that I haven't been able to find an easy way to convert to.

I need to convert:

1900-01-01 00:00:00.000

to

1/1/1900 12:00 AM

I've tried several combos of datepart with casting, but I haven't had much luck. I suppose I'll need to convert a couple of times to get what I want, but I figured I would ask the experts first.

Thanks!

Comment: a "SQL timestamp" or a Datetime? Timestamps should not be used to represent datetime...

Comment: Is it stored as a string or a datetime field?

Comment: Sorry, semantics. It's stored as a datetime field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I ended up finding the desired result with a colleague.

Here is what it ended up being, just in case anyone else needs it.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), EDITDATE, 101) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, EDITDATE,100),7) AS ConvertedDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to format a date into a string?  If so take a look at this page:

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx

Towards the bottom of the page is something that looks just like what you are looking for:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), SYSDATETIME(), 22)  -->   06/08/11 1:30:45 PM
```

Comment: This conversion is a little different as it's only 2 digits for the year and it also includes seconds. I'm thinking there's no direct conversion, which is why I guess I have to run through several conversions. Still unsure on what the most expedient method would be.